# Src changing works in Firefox, not in IE/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, list, drop-down-menu, midi

I am attempting to create a drop-down list that will automatically play a midi file in the background when the onchange event fires. This is working fine in Firefox, but IE and Chrome don't even bring up the QuickTime player when they're supposed to. I've tested the embed code with a static source and it works fine in all three browsers.

```
<form name="music">
    <select name='audiomenu' onchange="midiplay(this);">
        <option value="">No Music</option>
        <option value="midi/1.mid">Background 1</option>
        <option value="midi/2.mid">Background 2</option>
     </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function midiplay(what) {   
        document.getElementById('midijuke').src = what.options[what.selectedIndex].value;
    }
</script> 

<embed src="#" id="midijuke" autostart="true" loop="true" type="audio/midi" width="120" height="40"></embed>
```

IE and Chrome do not report any JavaScript errors either.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa, Do you have a better suggestion?  MIDI files aren't typically supported for playback with HTML5's `<audio>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Using the DOM (because it does DOM manipulation easier than jQuery):

```
var juke = document.getElementById('midijuke');

juke.src = 'http://blah.com/foo.mid';

juke.parentNode.removeChild(juke).appendChild(juke);
```

HTML markup belongs in HTML documents, not JavaScript strings. The wrapper should go in the document, not a string. The proper way to manipulate the DOM is with the DOM APIs.

Comment: You're copied both my post, my edit and my comment and you're holding on to your POV in a stubborn manner. Update your answer, remove `removeChild(juke).appendChild(juke)` and now try to append juke in the same position with respect to other elements inside its container (`juke.parentNode`).

Comment: Oh, that. `juke.parentNode.insertBefore(juke, juke)` ought to work, actually. I sort of like the post the way it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the whole thing and reattach it to the document. It saves you all the hassle.

```
function midiplay(w) {   
    var j=document.getElementById('midijuke');
    j.src = w.options[w.selectedIndex].value;
    j.parentNode.insertBefore(j,j);
}
```